# How does "Appreciate" button in Behance works? vote once, not (only) cookies

Tags: javascript, ajax

How do you think Behance did their "Appreciate" button? (in the bottom of every page, for example: http://www.behance.net/Gallery/The-Jazz-09-Journal/349710)

You can only click once, after you click it says "thanks" and if you reload the page the button disappears.

If you delete the cookies, the button still doesn't show.

Anyone has a clue? Do you think they check IP addresses?

Comment: If there are no cookies, you can either put it down to something like a query string, or an IP and/or User Agent combo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the way;)
http://tutorialzine.com/2010/07/click-to-appreciate-badge-ajax-jquery-css/

Answer (score 1):

From my experience of web design, that is the conventional way of making that happen (checking for IP addresses OR User-agents that is and not cookies). The way I know it is because:

1. Do it in Chrome, works for the first time and doesn't work subsequently
2. Do it in Chrome's Incognito Mode, doesn't work anymore
3. Open up Firefox, it still doesn't work

This means that they are using IP or User-agent to make this happen. It should've worked with Firefox if they were using cookies.

Comment: Thanks Legend, good observation.
Do you know what happens if you are sharing one IP with many computers?

Comment: I think I am behind such a scenario but I don't have another computer to test it with. Let me see if I can get access from somewhere.

Comment: It can't be User-Agent either, if it works across FF & Chrome